# Not using pthread_detach or pthread_join, will not clean up the resources for other newly created threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

```
Below is my code snippet.



int main ( )
    {
     some instructions;
     while ( 1 )
     {
       /* Block 1 : Starts*/
       if ( selection == 1 )
       {
         ret = pthread_create ( &tid, NULL, &select_n_process_req, NULL );
         if ( ret != 0 )
         {
           printf ("Error Creating Thread");
         }
       }
       /* Block 1 : Ends*/

       /* Block 2 : Starts*/
       printf ("Sleeping for [%d]", retry_time * 60 * 60);
       for ( i = 0; i < retry_time * 60 * 60; i++ )
       {
          if ( stop_flag == 1 )
          {
           printf ("Process Stopped\n");
           break;
          }
          sleep ( 1 );
       }
       /* Block 2 : ENDS*/
     }
     some instructions;
     return SUCCESS;
    }

    int select_n_process_req ( void )
    {
     some instructions;
     return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Explanation of the Code:

1. Block 1: The variable "selection" will always be 1 and the thread
   will be created always for doing some task.
2. Block 2: Once the thread is created, this blocks waits for
   "retry_time ( usually will 1 hour )" again to create a new thread
   for doing the same task.

Question:

1. I am not calling any pthread_join or pthread_detach, but I am
   returning(which will terminate the thread) from the function
   "select_n_process_req". Will this not clear the resources allocated
   to pthread_create?
2. I found it strange that after some load, pthread_create was not
   called at all. Is this because I am not using pthread_detach or
   pthread_join?

Thank You.

Comment: Well they will be cleaned up when you exit your program, but if the program is long running and creates a lot of short-running threads, the resources used will accumulate.

Comment: As for the "clear the resources", just exiting a thread doesn't free anything you allocate in the thread, or close anything you open. You have to do that implicitly in the threads. Also, when a thread exits the returned value must be stored somewhere, and if you don't call `pthread_join` the data for that returned value will reside in memory until the process ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to either call **pthread_join** (from parent thread), or **pthread_detach**, or create the thread in detached state by passing additional attributes to **pthread_create**. See here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html

Comment: does not calling pthread_detach or pthread_join causes pthread_create to fail creating the thread.

Comment: No, both of these functions require the thread id as the argument, so you can only call them after having sucessfully created a thread

Comment: the problem here is pthread_create got failed. As pthread_create is calling every one hour, will "not clearing the resources" has caused the pthread_create to fail. Am I thinking right here?

Comment: It probably failed because the previously-created threads were never cleaned up via pthread_join etc, so your process maxed out on some resource limit, like stack memory. You can confirm this by checking its return value for known error codes documented in the manpage.